# Haskell Nested List Comprehensions

Tags: list, function, haskell, nested, list-comprehension

I am studying for an exam and I am looking at an example of nested list comprehensions from the book "Learn you a Haskell", and I was hoping if anyone could explain me step by step how to analyze it and come out with its output.

```
let xxs = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5]]

[ [ x | x <- xs, even x] | xs <- xxs ]]
```

Output: `([[2],[2,4],[4]])`

Answer (score 1):

```
[ [ x | x <- xs, even x] | xs <- xxs ]
[ [ x | x <- xs, even x] | xs <- [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5]] ]
[ [ x | x <- [1,2,3], even x] , [ x | x <- [2,3,4], even x] , [ x | x <- [4,5], even x] ]
[filter even [1,2,3], filter even [2,3,4], filter even [4,5]]
[[2],[2,4],[4]]
```

Or

```
[ [ x | x <- xs, even x] | xs <- xxs ]
map (\xs -> [ x | x <- xs, even x] ) xxs
map (\xs -> filter even xs) [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5]]
[filter even [1,2,3], filter even [2,3,4], filter even [4,5]]
[[2],[2,4],[4]]
```

Note this isn't the transformation that GHC actually does, just a way of writing it that might help you understand the output.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions could have been defined by few identities:

```
[ f x | x <- [],  ... ]       ===   []
[ f x | x <- [y], ... ]       ===   [ f y | {y/x}... ]   -- well, actually, it's
                                    -- case y of x -> [ f y | {y/x}... ] ; _ -> []

[ f x | x <- xs ++ ys, ...]   ===   [ f x | x <- xs, ...] ++ [ f x | x <- ys, ...]

[ f x | True, ...]            ===   [ f x | ... ]
[ f x | False, ...]           ===   []
```

The handling of *complex* *patterns* (as opposed to simple variable patterns) is elided, only hinted at, for simplicity. `{y/x}...` means, `y` is substituted for `x` in `...`. For actual definition, see [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11).

It follows that

```
[ f x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]   ===  concat [ [f x | x <- xs] | xs <- xss]
```

and

```
[ f x | x <- xs, test x ]     ===  map f (filter test xs)
```

Your expression is equivalent to

```
[ [ x | x <- xs, even x] | xs <- xxs ]   -- `]`, sic!
=
[ f xs | xs <- xxs ]  where  f xs = [ x | x <- xs, even x]
```

Which is to say, there's nothing special about a list comprehension being used as a value expression in the definition of `f`. It looks "nested", but actually, it isn't.

What *is* nested, are the generator expressions separated by commas:

```
[ x | xs <- xss, x <- xs ]   ===   concat [ [x | x <- xs] | xs <- xss ]
--              ^^^ nested generator
```

(the equivalency like we saw above.) So then,

```
[ [ x | x <- xs, even x] | xs <- [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5]] ]
=
[ [ x | x <- [1,2,3], even x]] ++ [[ x | x <- [2,3,4], even x]] ++ [[ x | x <- [4,5], even x] ]
=
[ [ x | x <- [1,2,3], even x], [ x | x <- [2,3,4], even x], [ x | x <- [4,5], even x] ]
=
[ [ x | x <- [1], even x]++[ x | x <- [2], even x]++[ x | x <- [3], even x]
, [ x | x <- [2], even x]++[ x | x <- [3], even x]++[ x | x <- [4], even x]
, [ x | x <- [4], even x]++[ x | x <- [5], even x] ]
=
[ [ 1 | even 1]++[ 2 | even 2]++[ 3 | even 3]
, [ 2 | even 2]++[ 3 | even 3]++[ 4 | even 4]
, [ 4 | even 4]++[ 5 | even 5] ]
=
[ []++[ 2 ]++[], [ 2 ]++[]++[ 4 ], [ 4 ]++[] ]
=
[ [2], [2,4], [4] ]
```

Or, with `filter` if you'd prefer,

```
[ [ x | x <- [1,2,3], even x], [ x | x <- [2,3,4], even x], [ x | x <- [4,5], even x] ]
=
[ filter even [1,2,3], filter even [2,3,4], filter even [4,5] ]
=
[ [2], [2,4], [4] ]
```